# Generating function of (-3)^n

Tags: generating-functions

Given the sequence $a_n$, where $n$-th element is $a_n = (-3)^n$

I have the generating function 
$$A(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-3)^nt^n $$

The problem now is to simplify the obtained expression.

**I did the following:**

Let $B(t) = -3t$  be the generating function
and $C(B(t)) = A(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-3)^nt^n $.
Hence, the generating function $C(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^n = \frac{1}{1 - t}$

Therefore 
$$A(t) = C(B(t)) = C(-3t) = \frac{1}{1 + 3t}$$

Is this a possible way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your basic approach is correct, but $C(t)=\frac1{1-t}$, not $\frac{t}{1-t}$; $\frac{t}{1-t}=\sum_{i\ge 1}t^n$. Thus, the numerator of $A(t)$ should also be $1$.

Comment: @Brian M. ScottBy  the way. I don't think why we consider that $|t| < 1$?

Comment: If you want the series to converge, you need to take $|-3t|=3|t|<1$, so you actually want $|t|<\frac13$.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott As a result, I have to replace $\frac{t}{1 - t}$ by $\frac{1}{1 - t}$ or to change the numerator?

Comment: Replace $\frac{t}{1-t}$ by $\frac1{1-t}$; you should then get the correct result for $A(t)$.

Comment: Looks good now.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply notice that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-3)^nt^n$ is a convergent geometric series with ratio $-3t$ for $\|3t\|< 1$.

The closed form of geometric series with ratio $r$, where $\|r\| < 1$, is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n = \frac{1}{1-r}.
$$